# Swift How to add Title Text of UIRefreshControl in 2 rows

Tags: xcode, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I add a RefreshControl to View with long title text, but this title be hidden some word.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Last Updated at Some time...Pull to refersh your content")
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```

Comment: How is it initialized, i.e. has `UIRefreshControl` a frame?

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the UILabel of the UIRefreshControl and set the number of lines to 0 to allow multiple lines. After that you can add `\n` to set a line break. (I didn't test this code. Check if the method to get the UILabel is correct. Maybe you have to alter it. I will update it later)

```
var titleLabel = self.refreshControl.subviews.firstObject.subviews.lastObject

if(titleLabel != nil){
  titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
  var title = "Last Updated at Some time... \nPull to refersh your content"
  self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title)
}
```

Comment: I can't find any answer how to do Insert UILabel as Title.